# Trouble with X Axis time units in Gantt charts with Mermaid via DiagrammeR

Tags: r, intervals, mermaid, diagrammer, gant

So I can't get any of the fixes ([1](https://mermaid.js.org/syntax/gantt.html#syntax), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55922237/3348414), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29999300/3348414)) I've seen working on RStudio for changing the units of the x axis to days, weeks or months. I dont know how to get [this option](https://github.com/mermaid-js/mermaid/issues/269#issuecomment-373229136) to work.

Example:

```
library(DiagrammeR)
mermaid("
gantt
    title Gantt
    dateFormat  DD-MM-YYYY
    axisFormat %d/%m

    section One
    Task One            : 07-05-2019, 7d
    Task Two            : 09-05-2019, 7d ")
```

It just shows a white window with black text instead of a normal gantt chart.

[image]

Without the axis part, it runs just fine.

[image]